# Twig: Template in template in for loop

Tags: php, templates, twig

I'm loading a twig template and it contains a `for` loop with runs through a variable of type array and outputs ok, now I'm trying to include a snippet of html within the for loop and pass in the data from the loop and populate the sub template.

**mainSet.template.php**

```
{% for set in sets %}
    {% include 'inner/set.template.php' with {'set'} only %}
{% endfor %}
```

`inner/set.template.php`, inner is a sub-folder within the directory that `mainSet.template.php`exists in.

**set.template.php**

```
<div class="set">
    <span>{{ set.name }}</span>
</div>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "}" ("punctuation" expected with value ":") in "index" at line 4.' in C:\htdocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\TokenStream.php:87
Stack trace:
#0 C:\htdocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(284): Twig_TokenStream-&gt;expect(9, ':', 'A hash key must...')
#1 C:\htdocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(188): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;parseHashExpression()
#2 C:\htdocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(84): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;parsePrimaryExpression()
#3 C:\htdocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(41): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;getPrimary()
#4 C:\htdocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\TokenParser\Include.php(46): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;parseExpression()
#5 C:\htdocs\ in C:\htdocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\TokenStream.php on line 87
```

The code is to broken up over a custom framework to post it all here, the initial twig template is loaded like below and an array of set data is passed in.

```
 $twigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Array(array(
      'index' => file_get_contents((!empty($dirLevel) ? $dirLevel : '').TEMPLATE_DIR . 'index' . TEMPLATE_EXT)
 ));
 ...
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($twigLoader);
 $page = $twig->render('index', $indexData);
```

**$indexData**

```
Array
(
    [sets] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test 1
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test 2
        )

        [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test 3
        )
    )
)
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying, I know you can include templates in templates so maybe I have some syntax wrong!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `{% include 'inner/set.template.php' with {'set'} only %}` to `{% include 'inner/set.template.php' with {'set':set} only %}`

syntax for associative arrays is `{key1:value1, key2:value2, ...}`

Comment: setting `'set'` with quotes is optional on a hash key